# ZSH: zcompile doesn't work when a file start with →

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, zsh

So, for reproducing:

```
touch reddit
touch →reddit
```

Try: `zcompile reddit` and you will have a `.zwc` file in your current dir
BUT when you run `zcompile →reddit`, you get an error:

```
$ zcompile →reddit
zcompile: can't open file: →reddit
```

Have you ever experienced this issue ? Do you have any solutions or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. You should report it on the [official Zsh mailing list](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Arc/mlist.html).